# RxJs race function - make sure that the first to occur wins

Tags: rxjs

I have 2 different Observables, let's call them **racer_1** and **racer2**, which emit when 2 different events occur.

If **racer_1** occurs I have to perform the logic of function **doStuff_1()**, if **racer_2** occurs I have to perform **doStuff_2()**.

**racer_1** and **racer_2** are not mutually exclusive and they can occur one after the other, but what I want to achieve is that if any of them occur, I process just that one with its associated function.

It seems clearly the case of using the `race` function of RxJs.

```
race(
    racer_1.pipe(
        tap(() => doStuff_1()),
        finalize(() => console.log('racer 1 completed'))
    ),
    racer_2.pipe(
        tap(() => doStuff_2()),
        finalize(() => console.log('racer 2 completed'))
    )
)
```

Unfortunately though it may happen that **racer_1** emits first at *t0* and **doStuff_1()** starts a synchronous execution which ends at *t0+1000*.

In the meantime, at *t0+200* **racer_2** emits and the execution of **doStuff_2()** is much shorter so that it ends at *t0+300*.

In this case what I see is that **racer_2** "wins the race" and its emissions continue to get processed, while **racer_1** gets completed.

On the contrary what I would like to see is that **racer_1** wins since it occurred first, even if its processing can get long to be completed.

Is there a way to obtain such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reorder operators and wrap the initial emissions from both source Observables and perform `doStuff_1` or `doStuff_2` later:

```
race( // wrap emissions with tmp objects
    racer_1.pipe(map(result => { type: 'racer1', result })),
    racer_2.pipe(map(result => { type: 'racer2', result })),
  )
  .tap(({ type, result }) => type === 'racer1'
    ? doStuff_1() 
    : doStuff_2()
  )
  map(({ type, result }) => result) // unwrap the object
```

Comment: I was looking for another trick from the operators' hat, but this is clear and good - Thanks